# Fill table with dynamic amount of columns

Tags: tables

I want to fill a table with a dynamic (calculated) amount of columns. The column should be filled with a value which the user should provide comma separated. I therefore tried to use [forcsvloop](http://ctan.vgtu.lt/macros/latex/contrib/etextools/etextools.pdf), but I must have made some mistakes, as I got a strange error:

```
Undefined control sequence ^^I\entry{5,6,7}
```

with example

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etextools}

%Create a table with a specific amount of columns
\newenvironment{vartab}[1]
{
    \begin{tabular}{ |c@{} *{#1}{r|} } \hline
}{
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\entry}[1]{
    \forcsvloop{#1}\do{
        & ##1
    }\\ \hline
}

\begin{document}

\begin{vartab}{3}
    & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
    \entry{5,6,7}
\end{vartab}

\end{document}
```

Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: Note that TeX is not “free form” and end-of-lines are significant: they're translated into spaces that may or may not appear in the output; several of your end-of-lines do appear in the output.

Comment: @egreg What kind of "end-of-lines" do you mean, the manual ones ("\\") or the raw newline characters ("\n") in my example?

Comment: The raw newlines. For instance, you get spaces before and after the table, which you can check with `X\begin{vartab}{3}&2&3&4\\\hline\end{vartab}X`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A simpler way to do this is using an auxillary macro, to simplify expansion:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{etextools}

%Create a table with a specific amount of columns
\newenvironment{vartab}[1]
{
    \begin{tabular}{ |c@{} *{#1}{r|} } \hline
}{
    \end{tabular}
}

\newcommand{\myformat}[1]{& #1}

\newcommand{\entry}[1]{
  \edef\result{\csvloop[\myformat]{#1}}
  \result \\ \hline
}

\begin{document}


\begin{vartab}{3}
    & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
    \entry{5,6,7}
\end{vartab}

\end{document}
```

As a completely different approach note that `tabular` is built on top of the tex primitive `\halign` that builds tables row by row.  This primitive has an vertical analogue `\valign` that works columnwise:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\valign{\hrule\vskip 2pt plus 1fil\hbox{\strut\quad #\quad}\vfil&
\hrule\vskip 2pt plus 1 fil \hbox{\strut\quad #\quad}
\vskip 1pt plus 1fil\hrule\cr
\noalign{\vrule}
2&5\cr
\noalign{\vrule}
3&6\cr
\noalign{\vrule}
4&7\cr
\noalign{\vrule}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Great, and much better as my approach, thank you! Anyways, just to learn from my mistakes, do you know what I did wrong?

Comment: It is a problem with expansions, but I didn't get to the bottom of it.

Answer (score 5):

You're trying to begin the loop in a cell and end it in another, which isn't possible because table cells form groups; it's like improperly nesting environments

```
\begin{A}
\begin{B}
...
\end{A}
\end{B}
```

which can't work.

Here's a way with `etoolbox` (I can't recommend using `etextools` that's buggy and unmaintained).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%Create a table with a specific amount of columns
\newenvironment{vartab}[1]
  {\begin{tabular}{ |c@{} *{#1}{r|} } \hline}
  {\end{tabular}}

\newcommand{\doentry}[1]{\appto\temp{& #1}}

\newcommand{\entry}[1]{%
  \def\temp{}% initialize to empty
  \forcsvlist{\doentry}{#1}% add entries
  \appto\temp{\\ \hline}% end the row
  \temp % deliver contents
}

\begin{document}

\begin{vartab}{3}
    & 2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
    \entry{5,6,7}
\end{vartab}

\end{document}
```

The loop is completely worked out in the first cell, by adding to a temporary command that's expanded at the end.

A different solution uses `xparse` and `expl3`; note that the dummy first column is not needed any more.

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xparse}

%Create a table with a specific amount of columns
\newenvironment{vartab}[1]
  {\begin{tabular}{ |*{#1}{r|} } \hline}
  {\end{tabular}}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\entry}{m}
 {
  \clist_set:Nn \l_muffel_row_clist { #1 }
  \clist_use:Nn \l_muffel_row_clist { & }
  \\
  \hline
 }
\clist_new:N \l_muffel_row_clist % allocate a clist variable
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{vartab}{3}
  2 & 3 & 4 \\\hline
  \entry{5,6,7}
\end{vartab}

\end{document}
```

[image]