# Create a table column by column with special border formatting

Tags: tables

I need to create some tables for a special college report. The data provided specifies the values column by column.

The user Andrew Swann pointed out, that there is a way to [create TeX tables column by column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127960/fill-table-with-dynamic-amount-of-columns?noredirect=1#answer-127969) which was completeley new to me, but would be a great benefit for my special purpose.

Unfortunately I neither understand those commands nor didn't find a good documentation for that. What I need is a table with borders around each single cell except for the first cell and the whole last row. Below is an example how it would look like using the *regular* syntax.

Could you please tell me how I can create such a table by building it columnwise?

[image: Result of example code]

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|l|l|}
    \cline{2-3}
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{a} & b & c \\ \hline
    d & e & f \\ \hline
    g & h & i \\ \hline
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{j}  &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{k}  &
    \multicolumn{1}{l}{l}  &
\end{tabular}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The macros `\halign` and `\valign` are documented in the TeXbook.  More accurately `\halign` is described in detail there, and `\valign` is introduced briefly, saying that is analogous.

The `\valign` statement starts with a preamble than has the form

```
pre-row-1 # post-row-1& pre-row-2 # post-row-2& .... & ... # post-row-n\cr
```

the table material is for the given column is inserted in place of the `#`'s much as in macros.  A short cut is that an extra `&` at the beginning or immediately after another `&`, means that the format material from that point up to the `\cr` is repeated for all subsequent rows.  Thus a preamble

```
&pre-row # post-row\cr
```

produces an arbitrary number of rows with the same format.

In the table you add entries in the usual way; rows separated by `&`, column ending with `\cr`.  A complete column format specification can be replaced by other material via `\noalign{...}`; so `\noalign{\vrule}` produces a vertical rule the whole way down the table.  A single row is replaced by writing `\omit<...>` where `<...>` is the new material.  The analogue of `\multicolumn` is `\multispan`, thus `\multispan3<...>` will spread `<...>` over three rows.

Here is your example:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\valign{% Preamble
&\hrule\vskip 2pt plus 1fil\hbox{\strut\quad #\quad}\vfil\cr
%         First rule empty row one, span across rows 2 and 3, empty in row 4
\omit&\multispan2\leaders\vrule\vfil&\omit\cr
%         First column, first cell has non-standard format without rule
\omit \vskip 2.4pt plus 1fil\hbox{\strut\quad a\quad}\vfil&d&g&j\cr
%         Second vertical rule, span rows 1 to 3, empty row 4
\multispan3\leaders\vrule\vfil&\omit\cr
%         Second column, all cells are regular
b&e&h&k\cr
\multispan3\leaders\vrule\vfil&\omit\cr
c&f&i&l\cr
\multispan3\leaders\vrule\vfil&\omit\cr}

\end{document}
```

The preamble says each row starts with a horizontal rule, a vertical space of `2pt` that can stretch followed by a horizontal box containing the material (padded with `\quad` space on each size and with a guaranteed minimum height and depth from `\strut`) followed by stretchable vertical space.

`\leaders\vrule\vfil` is what `\vrulefill` ought to be, but the command happens not to be defined, this is used in combination with `\multispan` to draw the vertical rules over the appropriate rows.

When we use `\omit` for the box containing `a` we have to provided the relevant parts of the formatting that we still need.  The extra `.4pt` on the `\vskip` accounts for the thickness of the `\hrule`.

An alternative approach to the whole table would be to provide separate rows for the rules, but then this essentially doubles the number of `&`s we have to write.

Answer (score 1):

`stackengine` package builds stacks vertically. I EDITED the answer to make sure it works with changes in `\fboxsep` and `\fboxrule`.  Two examples shown below.  A further EDIT allows for cell content to be of variable width.  There are five parameters you can adjust, `fboxrule`, `\fboxsep`, `\mystrutheight`, `\mystrutdepth`, and `\horzbuffer`.  The last of these is the horizontal gap added to the cell width.

EDITED to reflect name change of internal routine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{readarray}
% YOU CONTROL THE NEXT FIVE LINES
\fboxsep=3pt
\fboxrule=.25pt
\def\mystrutheight{.7\baselineskip}
\def\mystrutdepth{.1\baselineskip}
\def\horzbuffer{2ex}
%
\def\mybox{}
\newcounter{index}
\newlength\cellwidth
\newlength\colwidth
\newcommand\myLongstack[1]{%
  \renewcommand\mybox[1]{##1}%
  \getargsC{#1}%
  \setlength\colwidth{0pt}%
  \setcounter{index}{0}%
  \whiledo{\value{index} < \narg}{%
    \stepcounter{index}%
    \setlength\cellwidth{\widthof{\csname arg\roman{index}\endcsname}}%
    \ifthenelse{\cellwidth > \colwidth}{%
      \setlength\colwidth{\the\cellwidth}}{}%
  }%
  \setlength\colwidth{\the\colwidth + \horzbuffer}%
  \xdef\myboxwidth{\the\colwidth}%
  \renewcommand\mybox[1]{\kern -\fboxrule\protect\framebox[\myboxwidth]{%
    \protect\rule[-\mystrutdepth]{0ex}{\mystrutheight}\smash{##1}}}%
  \Longstack{#1}%
}
\setstackgap{L}{\mystrutheight+2\fboxsep+\fboxrule}
\begin{document}
\myLongstack{a         \mybox{d} \mybox{g} j}%
\myLongstack{\mybox{b} \mybox{e} \mybox{h} k}%
\myLongstack{\mybox{c} \mybox{f} \mybox{i} l}
%
\fboxsep=4pt
\fboxrule=1pt
\def\mystrutheight{.7\baselineskip}
\def\mystrutdepth{.15\baselineskip}
\myLongstack{a         \mybox{d} \mybox{g} j}%
\myLongstack{\mybox{b} \mybox{eeeee} \mybox{h} k}%
\myLongstack{\mybox{c} \mybox{f} \mybox{i} l}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Your solution provides an easy way to achieve the example pattern, but unfortunately the boxes don't 'grow' like columns do. If I e.g. change 'e' to 'eeeeee', is there any way to modify the solution (only) the second column grows to hold the new content without line breaks?

Comment: @muffel  Will you know which is the widest element in a column, or could it be anywhere in each column?

Comment: Could be anywhere. The content is dynamically generated, and I do not have any influence on the content itself or its order.

Comment: @muffel  Revised to do as you ask.